# Syntax for creating foreign key index inline in create table statement

Tags: oracle, ddl, oracle19c

I want to create a table `bar` with a named foreign key constraint backed by a named index. I would like to do that with an inline definition in the create table DDL statement. When looking at the [Oracle 19 SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html) it looks like Oracle should support doing this inline.

When executing the following statements...

```
create table foo (
    id number not null primary key
);

create table bar (
    id     number not null primary key,
    nick   varchar2(16) not null constraint foo_nick_ck unique using index,
    foo_id number not null constraint foo_fk references foo using index
);
```

Oracle will respond with `[42000][907] ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` and point at the position just before the `using index` on the last line. If I remove `using index` it works (but without index being created of course). I've kept the column `nick` as an example of where it works to create the backing index inline, but for a unique constraint instead of a foreign key constraint.

I am aware that a workaround is to create the backing index in a separate DDL statement, but I would very much like to have it neat and tidy inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52163):

> You can specify the using_index_clause only when enabling unique or
>   primary key constraints
>
> You cannot specify this clause for a `NOT NULL`, *foreign key*, or
>   check constraint.

Answer (score 3):

> I am aware that a workaround is to create the backing index in a separate DDL statement, but I would very much like to have it neat and tidy inline.

Unfortunately the syntax does not exist to create indexes inline.

The USING INDEX clause is syntactic sugar: Oracle creates indexes to enforce Primary Key and Unique constraints regardless of whether we include that clause **(*)**. This is because an index is necessary to Oracle's implementation of unique constraints. But there is no such need for an index to enforce a foreign key, it's just desirable.

---

**(*)** Unless there's an existing index on the constrained column(s) which Oracle can use.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I wish I could accept your answer too!